# Creating a new dictionary from a csv file and using it for multiple functions

Tags: python, csv, class, dictionary

Basically want to extract values from a csv file, and create a global dictionary that I can go ahead and use for my other functions.

I don't know if I used the right approach in creating a class so bear with me.

def spread_parse extracts the values I want from the csv file however, when run the function. My dictionary "pick" returns blank. 
I know this approach works because if I just combine function "def spread_parse" and function "def write" into a single function , it'll create a separate file with the values I want. The issue is that I would like to create other functions with the newly added values that is contained in my "pick" dictionary and with a single function, those values will just be restricted to that function. Please correct me if I am incorrect.

```
import csv


class Parse:

    def __init__(self, filename):
        self.filename = filename
        self.picks = {}

    def spread_parse(self):
    """Parses csv file"""
        f = open(self.filename)
        csv_f = csv.reader(f)


        a = []
        b = []
        # Add players names to players
        for row in csv_f:
            a.append(row[2])

        # Have to repull csv file to add prices
        f = open(self.filename)
        csv_f = csv.reader(f)

        # Add prices of each player
        for row in csv_f:
            b.append(row[5])

        # Copy a & b lists into players and prices to remove Players,      
        # Names columns
        players = a[1:]
        prices = b[1:]

        self.picks = dict(zip(players, prices))


    def write(self):
    # create a file name based on week

    file = 'PGA_Picks23.txt'

    with open(file, 'w') as f:
        for key, value in self.picks.items():
            picky = (key, value)
            f.writelines("\n" + str(picky))
```

Then I go ahead and run the class in a separate file.

```
import Eh as e
e.Parse('DKSal.csv').spread_parse()
e.Parse('DKSal.csv').write()
```

It just returns a blank file when I run both of those functions.

Answer (score 1):

You're creating two separate objects. You need to create a single Parse object and call both of the methods from it:

```
import Eh as e
parse = e.Parse('DKSal.csv')
parse.spread_parse()
parse.write()
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless there is a specific reason why you don't want to use [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/), I suggest that you do. Pandas have a wide range of input and output tools. Normally, one reads the data into a [DataFrame](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html) which is like a spreadsheet with rows and columns. Any row or any column by itself is called a [Series](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.html).
You can create dictionaries from dataframes using the `to_dict` method. The code could look similar to this:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv(your_csv)
# Do your data cleaning here.
# To create a dictionary
as_dict = df.to_dict(orient='list')
# To write back to a csv after some manipulations
df.to_csv(filename)
```